# All PUT Requests are blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, .net-5

I got a .NET 5 API with some cors-policies.

This are my CORS-settings:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("cors",
            builder => builder
                .WithOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:4200",
                    "http://127.0.0.1:4200",
                    "http://rev-staging.myhost.ch")
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
...
}
```

and of course `app.UseCors("cors");` in `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder, WebHostEnvironment )`

When I execute my methods on localhost, everything works.

As soon as I publish to `api-rev-staging.myhost.ch` and execute them on live-server, for all PUT-requests I get

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api-rev-staging.myhost.ch/api/v1/Vacancies/7' from origin 'http://rev-staging.myhost.ch' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

(I changed the URL because it's company URL)

All GET and POST requests do work - just the PUT-requests don't work. They neither work when executing from angular front-end on `http://rev-staging.myhost.ch` nor when executing from postman on my local machine - but the GET and POST still work.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Edit: maybe it's important. Backend runs on IIS, same server like frontend, just another hostname.

Comment: @gunr2171 actually yes. Because api- is the API (backend) and without api- is the angular frontend.

Comment: I only say that because you use the rev-staging subdomain in your cors settings, but not the api-rev-staging subdomain. Eh, I think you can ignore me anyways, I think I figured out why I was confused.

Comment: Try to check if your server accept PUT and DELETE for Web API. Out of the box these verbs are disabled: https://inthetechpit.com/2019/02/24/enable-put-and-delete-http-verbs-for-webapi-with-cors-on-iis-8-5/

Comment: @NicolaBiada this was the problem. had to edit the web.config and add the handler-things. thanks for the hint!

Comment: Ok, if you agree I copy the comment as answer

Comment: @NicolaBiada yeah sure, go for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if your server accept PUT and DELETE for Web API.
Out of the box these verbs are disabled.

Some documentation here:
https://inthetechpit.com/2019/02/24/enable-put-and-delete-http-verbs-for-webapi-with-cors-on-iis-8-5/